# How to upload Blob in Blocks directly to Azure?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am currently using Javascript paired with an Azure Shared Access Signature to upload files directly to Azure. As long as I keep the file size under 64MB there is no issue because the file is being sent up as 1 blob. However, when I go over that size I get an error saying the file size is too big. I know there is a work-around by cutting the blob into blocks, but I'm not sure how to do that with my current set up. Is there a way for me to upload a blob that is say 200MB by cutting it into blocks of 64MB only using Javascript and a Shared Access Signature?

Comment: I removed the SAS tag, as I don't think you're using SAS (programming language).

Comment: Please see this link: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/ (Ignore the notes about CORS not available as I wrote this post prior to CORS availability in Azure Storage).

Answer (score 0):

With help from Gaurav Mantri and the link he posted, I was able to make the necessary additions to chunk a 100MB video file and send it up directly to Azure from Javascript. A side note to go with the information provided in the link, when you decide to cut a blob into blocks and send up to Azure it is important to note that the max size a block can be is 4MB. Once I figured that out my upload worked flawlessly.